# PHP variable not being replaced with what's been collected

Tags: php

I am building a platform where a user can edit information. This includes a picture. It works when the picture is replaced but if the user does not add a new picture and wants to keep the old one, the picture disappears and it fills in blank in the database instead of keeping what was already there.

```
    <?
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    # Define all the standard values that were created in the form
    $picture = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $tags = $_POST['tags'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $xs = $_POST['xs'];
    $s = $_POST['s'];
    $m = $_POST['m'];
    $l = $_POST['l'];
    $xl = $_POST['xl'];
    $xxl = $_POST['xxl'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $sale = $_POST['sale'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    # checking the sizes and adjusting the values accordingly
    if ($xs=="on"){$xs="true";}else{$xs="false";};
    if ($s=="on"){$s="true";}else{$s="false";};
    if ($m=="on"){$m="true";}else{$m="false";};
    if ($l=="on"){$l="true";}else{$l="false";};
    if ($xl=="on"){$xl="true";}else{$xl="false";};
    if ($xxl=="on"){$xxl="true";}else{$xxl="false";};
    #defining the $size
    $sizes = $xs."&".$s."&".$m."&".$l."&".$xl."&".$xxl;
    #handling the picture that was uploaded
    if(isset($_FILES['file']))
    {
        #Putting all the information into the database
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../upload/'.$picture);
        $todo = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS values('','$name','$picture','$description','$tags','$color','$sizes','$price','$sale','$gender')";
        if (mysqli_query($con,$todo))
        {
            $notice = "The product has been added to the product list";
        }
        else
        {
            $notice = "The data could not be handled, please try again";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $notice = "The picture could not be handled, please try again";
    };
}
?>
```

EDIT: Added the whole code

Also quick sidenote, I am a student I don't really get overly complicated code (yet) so if you come with a 20 line solution I probably won't get it and don't learn a thing from it ><

Comment: it's your logic. You're doing `if(isset($_POST['submit'.$update[productID]]))` without also checking to see if a file was chosen to be uploaded. You should use that conditional statement AND add an `isset()` for the file, then an `else`.

Comment: *"and it fills in '' (nothing) in the database"* - there's nothing in your question to support this and as to what logic you're using for it. Question's unclear. Add full code.

Comment: As in it replaces what is in the database with nothing. It leaves it blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check file uploads like this:

```
if( !file_exists( $_FILES['file']['name'] ) || !is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['name'] ) ) {

    // Nothing uploaded ...

}
```

Comment: what kind of code/answer is this? as per original http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37599119/1

Comment: The problem is that it does know when there is no file uploaded but instead of doing $picture = $update[picturename]; it makes $picture blank so the database is empty. When a picture is updated it does actually replace it, only when there is no updated picture it goes wrong

Comment: `!file_exists( $_FILES['file']['name'] )` RTM on that function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: @Lucas Yes! (S)he should check if there is some file, and then update the DB. If not, no updates

Comment: Oh wow, yeah I have it update every time, even if nothing changes >< thanks, didn't think of that